# Find images on a specific directory on a web server

Tags: php, image, hidden

Is there a way to find the images on a directory on a web server? Let's say the profile with ID 123456 has some images on his profile. The images are being uploaded to example.com/123456/ and each image has its own unique name for the profile.

One of them is http://example.com/123456/jgU3oggfSc.jpg The image link can be seen only by the owner, but once revealed to the public, everyone can see it even if it's private. So, my question actually is, is there a way to search for images at "http://example.com/123456/"?

Comment: please post what have you tried so far

Comment: @DavidJhons I did not do anything. Imagine facebook, the same thing.. When a user uploads a photo, the back-end automatically renames it with a random name. My question is: can a hacker find your private photos just by making combinations of strings? Can he list all images on the directory without knowing the names of the images?

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can do that by creating an index file at http://example.com/123456/ and then generate the image in there that way the image url wont be shown.